# Automatic dependency list not generated in a different setting of directory structure

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following directory structure:

```
root-----Makefile
   |-----src  #all source files here.
   |-----obj  #all object files here.
   |-----bin  #the final target.
```

The contents of `Makefile` is given below:

```
TARGET  =       exec

CC              =       gcc
CFLAGS  =       -g -I.
LINKER  =       gcc -o
LFLAGS  =       -I. -lm -lpthread

BINDIR  =       bin
OBJDIR  =       obj
SRCDIR  =       src
INTERFACE =     interface
STD     =       -std=c99

PROGRAMSOURCES  :=      $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
PROGRAMINTERFACE:=      $(wildcard $(INTERFACE)/*.h)
OBJECTS         :=      $(PROGRAMSOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)     :       $(OBJECTS)
        $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(STD)

#pull the dependencies to the .o files
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)

$(OBJECTS)              :       $(OBJDIR)/%.o :$(SRCDIR)/%.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(STD)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $< > $*.d
        @mv -f $*.d $*.d.tmp
        @sed -e 's|.*:|$(OBJDIR)/$*.o:|' < $*.d.tmp > $*.d
        @sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\\$$//' < $*.d.tmp | fmt -1 | \
         sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$$/:/' >> $*.d`
        @rm -f $*.d.tmp`

.PHONY  :       run
run             :`
        ./$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) ${TYPE} ${INP_FILE}
```

I have used the tutorial [here](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) have been modified to suit the corresponding directory structure. But something has got wrong in the modification and I cannot understand what. The dependency list generated in the `.d` files is not taken into account *i.e.* if I change a `.h` the rules are not compiling.

Comment: Where do you want the dependency files to go?

Comment: They can go anywhere, I guess, as long as the dependency list is properly generated. I think that the "-include" is not working properly due to some modification I have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be producing the dependency files in `root/`, but looking for them in `obj/`.

Try changing this:

```
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

to this:

```
-include *.d
```

There are other improvements you can make, once the makefile is working.

**EDIT: further improvements**

1) The choice of where to put the dependency files is mainly arbitrary, but if we put them in `obj/`, we can simplify the `$(OBJECTS)` rule quite a lot:

```
-include $(OBJDIR)/*.d

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o :$(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@ $(STD)
```

2) `PROGRAMINTERFACE` and `INTERFACE` aren't used, so we can remove them.

3) Putting `-o` in `LINKER` like that is dangerous. And don't forget the automatic variable `$^`:

```
LINKER = gcc
$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINKER) $@ $(LFLAGS) $^ $(STD)
```

4) It would be wise to give `run` a prerequisite:

```
run: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    ./$< ${TYPE} ${INP_FILE}
```

Comment: Can you suggest what other improvements can I make?